# What kind of charging port is this?

Tags: electronic-items, aircraft

I thought it might be USB-C at first glance but it obviously isn't. Is it Apple Lightning? Or something else?[image]

I saw this on recent flights on Etihad and Vistara.

Comment: I just remembered the video where older people showing younger ones a cassette player...

Comment: I am actually pretty old haha :). This looked a little smaller than the typical USB-A port and did not have the "trident" sign, so I thought it might be USB-C but the connector didn't fit. On the connecting flight they had a USB port that was more familiar to me and I was able to use it to charge my phone.

Comment: @hojusaram it probably didn't have the USB logo because it doesn't implement the USB protocol, it only provides power (hence the charging logo).

Comment: Zooming in, it almost looks like the metal has been damaged, as if someone broke it by putting something too large in it.

Comment: @At0mic from OPs comment, I derive that that someone might be him :))

Comment: @littleadv It's a matter of certification. USB is an open standard, but the logo can only be legally put on certified products, and it's not free. IMO you can get a charging-only port certified if you need to.

Comment: Addressing the concerns listed in the answers about potential to damage your device when charging via the built in USB ports, simply use the AC plug available and the charger that comes with your device. According to this [Q&A on Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/38934/5517), that power will be quite clean, and you'll have the security of knowing that the only hacking of the USB port is the one you've done yourself. Plus the added bonus of getting full-rate charging for your high-current-draw device.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Looks like a USB-A female plug. Quite commonplace in international flights.

[image]

FYI:

- [Is it ever useful to allow access to phone data when connecting one's phone to an airplane USB plug?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/162981/1810)
- [List of USB connector types](https://superuser.com/a/1745352/116475)

Comment: "Quite commonplace in international flights." - I'd say even now (November 2022), USB-A is quite commonplace also on the other end of cables with a USB-C plug. What I *have* witnessed, though, (which might somewhat help to explain the OP's unfamiliarity with this plug) is that some users never realize the power plug part of e.g. phone charging cables can be disconnected (which is typically implemented as a USB-A connection).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper in April 2021 I bought a Motorola Moto G8 with a USB-C charging/data transfer port. It came with a wall-wart with a USB-A male to USB-C male lead. In a supermarket I spotted a longer lead in a nice pale green colour for £15 UK pounds. I bought it, more fool me, because in April 2022 I bought an new Lenovo desktop PC with a Turbo Charge USB-C outlet, and a free lead. So now I have 2 leads I don't need.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey you can still use it to charge your phone from a wall outlet adapter

Answer (score 44):

This is a standard USB-A charging port.

Answer (score 10):

As others have noted, this looks like a standard USB-A port, and cables are readily available *for charging* to connect USB-C to USB-A. USB-A ports are pretty much standard on all kinds of chargers - plug-in wall-warts, [permanently installed receptacles](https://amzn.to/3h5n6q8), [outlet strips](https://amzn.to/3sZKfx4).

There are two special concerns *using someone else's charger*:

- Security

It is *possible* (not saying "probable", but these things are out there in the wild) to hack in to a device via USB. A charger *should* only be sending power with no data, but you can't tell by looking at it. Not an issue to charge up your wireless headphones or other relatively simple devices, but potentially an issue for charging a smartphone. A malicious device could try to read information from your device or try to infect it with a virus or other malware.

The safest method, by far, is to plug in your own [wall wart](http://catb.org/jargon/html/W/wall-wart.html) into a mains (110V - 250V, depending on the country) connection, so that you are assured of only getting power from someone else's system and not any risk of data. But that is not always an option, and USB-A charging outlets are ubiquitous.

Thanks to Criggie for the reference to [USB Condom](https://zdnet.com/article/get-yourself-a-usb-condom) which is a device that solves this problem, though possibly at the cost of slower charging.

- Safety

There is a small possibility (e.g., see comment "*Zooming in, it almost looks like the metal has been damaged, as if someone broke it by putting something too large in it.*") of a damaged connector. USB *should* be smart enough to detect a problem and simply not charge. But there is a possibility of a damaged connector resulting in damage to your device rather than triggering a self-shutdown (e.g., breaker trip). Again, not easy to check for this as most people don't carry around a [USB tester](https://amzn.to/3NCex2q):

[image: USB Tester]

Sample picked semi-randomly from Amazon. Many different types are available.

Comment: Still overdoing the warning but I let it go like this.

Comment: I wonder whether a tester exists that can detect an active data line without being vulnerable to attack itself.

Comment: @WGroleau possibly, but it's simpler just to use a charge only cable that doesn't connect the data lines (though this can be slow)

Comment: Then you have to carry two cables and remember which is which.  Maybe a tester that also passes through the charging current but leaves the data lines open.

Comment: @WGroleau there are adapters/converters colloquially called a "USB Condom" which does exactly that.   Example https://www.zdnet.com/article/get-yourself-a-usb-condom/  downside, your device might charge at the slower 500mA even if device and charger can do more.   Adapter goes in-line with your normal charging cable.

Comment: @WGroleau Sure it can. Things aren't automatically vulnerable to attack - there has to be a specific weakness which makes them attackable. If the tester is just looking for any data signal, it's unlikely to have a weakness. The more stuff it does (like pretending to be different kinds of USB devices), the more likely it is to have a weakness that can be attacked.

Comment: @user253751, I knew it _can_.  I wondered whether one _exists_ that does.

Comment: Unless you've got a seriously old phone/tablet, nothing is going to let itself get read without user intervention...

Comment: @ScottishTapWater while I don't know if there are any such vulnerabilities, consumer operating systems have had numerous security vulnerabilities allowing access in ways not expected

Comment: Another great solution for the security and safety issues is charging up a powerbank and then using that powerbank to charge your device. Very practical for travelers as well since most will want a powerbank anyway :)

Comment: @FlorianWendelborn But watch out for the air travel rules regarding maximum Lithium batteries in your carry on. Just checked - [TSA says 100 Wh](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/lithium-batteries-100-watt-hours-or-less-device) so shouldn't *generally* but some larger powerbanks might be over the limit.